# Xcode 9 - TvOS - Launch images not working - Interface Bug?

Tags: swift, xcode, image, tvos, launch

Please help, my Launch screen images are not showing up. I have checked EVERYTHING and the only thing that looks out of place is in the interface the options for "Launch Image Source" is missing the "e" on source. I also think it should be showing "Launch Image File" but thats not there because I think it is failing to read this correctly out of some file and parse it.

My images are PNGs, with no Alpha layer, and the correct pixel sizes. I have tried cleaning and reloading, re-installing, etc. I have no warnings in Xcode.

I have tried to delete and recreate the Assets.xcassets folder, and delete and create the LaunchImage itself. I have tried removing the file extensions from the images as some suggested. The missing "e" in the interface seems to be the only thing out of place!

[image: Xcode Image]

Comment: Anyone got any ideas?!!

Comment: We're experiencing the same problem as well. We've checked everything and all seem to be all right, but the launch image doesn't show up.